# Why do people keep appearing in my village?

Tags: kingdom-two-crowns

Every night at the far right side of the base, a random 15ish people come out of a wall in my base. I don't know if it's a glitch or what, but it's really weird. I now have lots's of archers, and I'm wondering how I triggered it but I'd love to have this on other islands. Can someone tell me how this happened?

Comment: 15 of your villagers, or vagrants?

Comment: villagers- but completely new ones.